# Seizing a domain from dead primary domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

My old Primary Domain Controller died after a series of power problems.
I tried to follow this set of instructions http://kpytko.pl/active-directory-domain-services/seizing-fsmo-roles/ to get another windows server to be the Primary Domain Controller.
When I got to the "verify" part, things didn't go according to the instructions.
When I: 
"netdom query fsmo" I get: 
 
"The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
The command failed to complete successfully."
I have no experience with doing something like this.
What could have gone wrong, or what can I do to finish the process?

Comment: You have a secondary DC that also is a global catalog? That error sounds not like your pdc failed, but like you have no dc left at all that is qualified - in which case it is "goodbye domain" time.

Comment: I *thought* this one was set up as a secondary. but perhaps I was misinformed. :s Is there a way to tell?

Comment: The previous steps in the seizure  seemed to go as expected

Comment: Sorry, I meant to post this, but then it was too long, and then the edit expired.: The previous steps in the seizure  seemed to go as expected 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/78z5tgrwea4xzmb/seizure.txt?dl=0

Comment: Did you or did you not already have another Domain Controller in the domain? That's the question we need answered before we can provide you an answer.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty - I had Neptune as a primary and Saturn as a secondary. - When Neptune died, after about a day, some of the more picky machines on the network stopped wanting to talk to each other. - then I tried this to force Saturn to take it's role as the primary.

Comment: Is this helpful?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdzgh35vmsfjkis/Domain%20controllers.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Well, is Saturn a GC? If not - goodbye domain.

Comment: Global Catalogue was ticked when I went and looked in my NTDS settings for Saturn - https://www.dropbox.com/s/tr86tvjppi5gp7o/Global%20Catalogue.JPG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and questions.
In the end I wasn't able to find out what was going wrong with seizing the domain.
I brought the old controller back online after salvaging a power supply, and everything seems to be fine so far. If anything breaks, I guess I will have to create a new domain.